# Trigger a function when an element gets enabled/disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

This seems like a relatively simple thing but I can't find anything anywhere on how to do it. I have a modal that opens with a disabled input while waiting for async data. I want to know when that input becomes enabled to I can focus the input. This is what I'm trying to accomplish. Think of it as a global modal open handler:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var textInput = $(event.target).find('input[type=text]:visible').first();
    if (textInput.is(':disabled'))
    {
        textInput.on('<<<<<enabled>>>>>', function(){
            textInput.off('<<<<<enabled>>>>>');
            textInput.focus();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        textInput.focus();
    }
});
```

Is there not an event that gets triggered when an input becomes enabled/disabled?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control txtUserSearch" data-bind="value: userFilter, event: { keyup: FilterUsers }, enable: AvailableUsers().length > 0">
```

Which becomes enabled if there are users returned in an async request.

Comment: What disables/enables it?

Comment: This is a knockoutjs app so when the data is available knockout enables it.

Comment: So where is the async data coming from? You'd have to hook into whatever methods are available for the async function, and without posting that, this is impossible to answer ?

Comment: Have you checked the knockout api/docs for any callbacks you have available? More often than not, well established libraries like knockout will realise you have these kinds of requirements and will expose events or callbacks for you to use.

Comment: Have you tried 'change' event ? `textInput.on('change'`

Comment: If i do something related to knockout then I will have to handle it on every page i need this since it would be scope bound.

Comment: Well then alter the 'scope' in which you're using it.

Comment: It's difficult to be more specific until you post, more specifically, about what knockout feature you're using. Something in knockout that you're using is affected the enabled state of your element, that 'something' is a big point in the right direction for you.

Comment: I added example knockout code. But I am trying to put the "focus" feature in some global code so that it applies everywhere. The point is so that I don't have to manually code the focus points on each modal that has async requests.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such thing as `onenabled` or `ondisabled` listeners. Input fields can only be enabled/disabled by JavaScript once the page has loaded (or by some user which is messing up with your HTML in his developer tools' inspector). For this reason, **if you want to detect those changes you'll have to use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)**, and listen for attribute mutations of the element you want, to check whenever the `disabled` property gets added to your input field.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('toggle'),
    input = document.getElementById('inp');

// This is just to demonstrate the behavior of the MutationObserver
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (input.disabled) input.disabled = false;
    else input.disabled = true;
});
                     

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (var i=0, mutation; mutation = mutations[i]; i++) {
        if (mutation.attributeName == 'disabled') {
            if (mutation.target.disabled) {
                // The element has been disabled, do something
                alert('You have disabled the input!');
            } else {
                // The element has been enabled, do something else
                alert('You have enabled the input!');
            }
        }
    };
});

// Observe attributes change
observer.observe(input, {attributes: true});
```

```html
<p>Try clicking the button to disable/enable the input!</p>
<input id="inp" type="text" placeholder="Write something...">
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

#### Additional info

The `MutationObserver` object is a newly introduced feature, and it isn't supported by old versions of some browsers: you can check the compatibility with any browser on [this page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver).

Comment: I didn't dv, but I marked it as a solution. It's not as elegant as I hoped but it gets the job done. Thanks.

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey yeah, I know, but it's actually the only valuable solution to detect such attribute modifications live :\

Answer (score 1):

I once had a project with it, but I lost the motivation to do it.
I searched for a way to do that kind of stuff, and I found that `MutationObserver` should be a good way to do it.

Take a look : [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

And maybe there too : [`Mutation Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't the best way, but [here I go](http://jsfiddle.net/w0kgkxp2/1/):

```
var timeToCheck = 1000, past = 0;

function wait_enable (element) {
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(element.is(":enabled")){
            element.focus();
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        /* //here you can set a limit
        past += timeToCheck;
        if (past > limit) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        */
    }, timeToCheck);
}

var textInput = $("input");
wait_enable(textInput);

$("button").on("click", function(){
    textInput.prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: This really isn't a good Idea... plus you're checking every 1000ms, which is one second: that's a really high delay!

Comment: I think it won't cause a high delay, because he want to wait the end of modal's loading-time, but ok... I prefer your solution